# Sonarqube coverage: ¿ Cómo interpretar y solucionar 'partially covered'?

Tags: c++, gcc, sonarqube

Estoy configurando y probando la cobertura del código fuente por los distintos *test*. Y el `sonarqube` me muestra unos resultados totalmente incomprensibles.

Por ejemplo, este trozo de código:

```
auto node_number = adjacencyMatrix.n_cols;
std::vector<bool> visited( node_number, false );
std::vector<std::vector<uword> > islands;
decltype( islands.size( ) ) island_idx = 0;
std::vector<uword> stack( node_number );

for ( uword node = 0; node < node_number; ++node ) {
    // Visited yet. Nothing.
    if ( !visited[ node ] ) {
        islands.emplace_back( );
```

Está situado justo al inicio de una de las funciones a *testear*, y dicha función tiene un solo argumento. Las primeras 5 líneas mostradas son simples declaraciones con asignación inicial.

Sin embargo, el `sonarqube` me dice que la cobertura del archivo es del 38%, cuando yo se que el test cubre **todas las funciones**. De hecho, me dice que está línea

```
std::vector<uword> stack( node_number );
```

está **parcialmente cubierta**, cuando es ¡ una simple declaración ! Y, aunque tuviéramos en cuenta todos las posibles llamadas al constructor, tampoco nos saldrían las cuentas: [el constructor de `std::vector< >`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) tiene 9 posibles formas de invocarse.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entiendo que el `sonarqube` no hace mas que *poner en bonito* los datos que recoge del archivo de entrada. Este último lo estoy generando así:

```
gcovr -r . -k --xml-pretty -o report.xml
```

Y las compilaciones de las distintas unidades de traducción se realizan, en última instancia, así:

```
g++ -g -Wall -Wpedantic -Wextra -Og -g3 -ggdb -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -std=c++17
```

¿ Cual sería la interpretación correcta de este *coverage test* ?

¿ Estoy usando los argumentos correctos al compilar y al llamar a `gcovr` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Las plantillas se compilan cuando el compilador encuentra un uso de las mismas. Es decir, el código fuente de las plantillas es **siempre público**.

Por otro lado, el estándar solo obliga (por simplificar) a que las clases de la STL tengan una interfaz determinada, es decir, no se mete en la implementación de estas clases, que es libre.

Lo que sucede aquí es que el constructor de `std::vector` acaba invocando un condicional en algún momento y sonarqube detecta que no se están verificando todos los posibles caminos que ofrece el código. ¿Qué condicional es? ¿Dónde está? Ni idea. Como te he dicho la implementación de la STL es libre. Es bastante probable que si lo pruebas con otro compilador el mensaje sea diferente (o incluso que no salga ninguno).

> ¿ Cual sería la interpretación correcta de este coverage test ?

La STL es algo probado y robusto. Debería funcionar sin problemas. Los errores que hagan referencia a llamadas de la STL puedes ignorarlos (como norma general).

> ¿ Estoy usando los argumentos correctos al compilar y al llamar a gcovr ?

NO tiene nada que ver. Es un mensaje debido a la implementación específica de `std::vector`